# I downloaded a Minecraft world but its level file is a power media player file and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I open Minecraft in the single player section it is not there and I have tried to find out how to make it a normal file but I'm just lost at this point I have been unable to play downloadable world's forever now and I don't know what to do.[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided screenshots of the files.

Comment: A proper screenshot with filename and filetype would be more helpful.

Comment: Nevermind I think I figured it out I just got rid of the file and used the old version and it works now

Comment: Can you share your solution with the rest of us?

Answer (score 3):

Place the directory containing the level file in your Minecraft saves directory. This is typically in your hidden appdata directory on Windows, so it is available at the path `%appdata%\.minecraft\saves`. Then, restart Minecraft.

As for the level file *appearing* as a PowerMedia file, it has to do with how Windows stores the type of a file. Windows stores file types by adding a dot and a few letters, called the extension; the extension is normally unique to the file type. The Minecraft level file has an extension of "dat", for data. PowerMedia, however, says, "Hey guys! I can open .dat files!" And Windows says, "Okay PowerMedia, I'll write down that .dat files are your thing!" which causes Windows to show that it's a PowerMedia file.